# pygame - Scrolling down page

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

My program in a nutshell is a Contacts App, which obviously means that a person needs to be able to store a number of contacts in the app, which in turn means that contacts are going to eventually go "off" the screen, so I need to be able to scroll down the page so that a person can see all their contacts and interact with a specific contact.

However, I'm in a bit of pickle... how do I do this? The problems I'm facing is that the app is a fixed width and height so I can't scroll down the page only to find that the background is going to be black because my rectangle was only sized to be as long as the apps window length. The other problem is I just don't know how to 'push' the screen up. I just have no idea.

Here is the code for the program so far:

```
import pickle
import operator
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
from itertools import groupby

#create Contact class
class Contact():
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, address, groupType,
                 telephone, mobile, email, photoField):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.address = address
        self.groupType = groupType
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.email = email
        self.photoField = photoField

    def showDetails(self):
        print("First Name:\t", self.firstName)
        print("Last Name:\t", self.lastName)
        print("Address:\t", self.address)
        print("Telephone:\t", self.telephone)
        print("Mobile:\t", self.mobile)
        print("Email:\t", self.email)

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        firstName = input("First Name: ")
        lastName = input("Last Name: ")
        address = input("Address: ")
        telephone = input("Telephone: ")
        mobile = input("Mobile: ")
        email = input("Email: ")
        return cls(firstName, lastName, address, None,

                   telephone, mobile, email, None)

class AddressBook():
    def __init__(self):
        self.contactsList = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))

    def addContact(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            contact = Contact.from_input()
        self.contactsList.append(contact)
        pickle.dump(self.contactsList, open("save.p", "wb"))

    def delContact(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            search = input("Search: ")
            for i in self.contactsList:
                if (i.firstName.lower() == search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() == search.lower()):
                    indexed = self.contactsList.index(i)
                    del self.contactsList[indexed]
                    pickle.dump(self.contactsList, open("save.p", "wb"))
                elif (i.firstName.lower() != search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() != search.lower()):
                    continue

    def contactInfo(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            search = input("Search: ")
            print()

            #display contact information
            for i in self.contactsList:
                if (i.firstName.lower() == search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() == search.lower()):
                    i.showDetails()
                    print()
                elif (i.firstName.lower() != search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() != search.lower()):
                    continue
                else:
                    print("No contacts\n")

    def contactSearch(self, contact = None):
        if contact is None:
            search = input("Search: ")
            print()

            for i in self.contactsList:
                if (i.firstName.lower() == search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() == search.lower()):
                    print(i.firstName, i.lastName)
                    print()
                elif (i.firstName.lower() != search.lower()) or (i.lastName.lower() != search.lower()):
                    continue
                else:
                    print("No contacts\n")

class Page():
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480)), caption = pygame.display.set_caption("Contacts")):
        self.screen = screen
        self.caption = caption

    def style(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (171,0,0), (0,0,320,63), 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (230,230,230), (0,63,320,417), 0)
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (120,0,0), (5,61), (320, 61), 2)

class MainPage(Page):
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480)), caption = pygame.display.set_caption("Contacts"), title = "Contacts"):
        Page.__init__(self, screen, caption)
        self.title = title

    def style(self):
        Page.style(self)
        titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 38)
        textSurface = titleFont.render(self.title, True, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.blit(textSurface, (5, 18))
        AddButton().shape()

    def printContacts(self):
        addressBook = AddressBook()
        addressBook.contactsList
        addressBook.contactsList.sort(key = lambda c: (c.lastName, c.firstName) if c.lastName else (c.firstName, ""))
        contactFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 18)
        y = 80

        for (key, g) in groupby(addressBook.contactsList, lambda c: c.lastName[0] if c.lastName else c.firstName[0]):
            groupName = contactFont.render(key, True, (171,0,0))
            self.screen.blit(groupName, (5, y))
            pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (0,0,0), (5,(y+20)), (320, (y+20)), 1)
            y += 30

            for i in g:
                name = i.firstName + " " + i.lastName
                textName = contactFont.render(name, True, (0,0,0))
                pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (210,210,210), (5,(y+20)), (320, (y+20)), 1)
                self.screen.blit(textName, (5, y))
                y += 30

class AddPage(Page):
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480)), caption = pygame.display.set_caption("Contacts"), title = "Add Contact"):
        Page.__init__(self, screen, caption)
        self.title = title

    def style(self):
        Page.style(self)
        titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 38)
        textSurface = titleFont.render(self.title, True, (255,255,255))
        self.screen.blit(textSurface, (5, 18))
        AddButton().shape()
        CancelButton().shape()

class Button():
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480))):
        self.screen = screen

    def shape(self): 
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (120,0,0), (270,12,40,40), 0)

class AddButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480))):
        Button.__init__(self, screen)

    def shape(self):
        Button.shape(self)
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (255,255,255), (289, 15), (289,48), 2)
        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (255,255,255), (272, 31.5), (307, 31.5), 2)

class CancelButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 480))):
        Button.__init__(self, screen)

    def shape(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (120,0,0), (245,20,25,25), 0)
        pygame.draw.aaline(self.screen, (255,255,255), (252,32.5), (263,26))
        pygame.draw.aaline(self.screen, (255,255,255), (252,32.5), (263,39))

pygame.init()
page = MainPage()
page.style()
page.printContacts()

while True:    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()  
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and isinstance(page, MainPage):
            if (pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (270,13)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (270,53)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (309,13)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (309,53)):
                page = AddPage()
                page.style()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1 and isinstance(page, AddPage):
            if (pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (270,13)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (270,53)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (309,13)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (309,53)):
                page = MainPage()
                page.style()
                page.printContacts()
            elif (pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (245,20)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (245,45)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (370,20)) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (370,45)):
                page = MainPage()
                page.style()
                page.printContacts()

    pygame.display.update()

    addressBook = AddressBook()
    addressBook.contactsList
    addressBook.contactsList.sort(key = lambda c: (c.lastName, c.firstName) if c.lastName else (c.firstName, ""))

    print("-------------------\nContacts\n")
    for i in addressBook.contactsList:
        print(i.firstName, i.lastName)
    print()

    print("Menu:\n\n1. Add Contact\n2. Show Contact Details\n3. Edit Contact\n4. Delete Contact\n5. Search Contact\n-------------------\n")

    choice = input()
    print()

    if choice == "1":
        #add contacts

        contact = AddressBook().addContact()

    elif choice == "2":
        contact = AddressBook().contactInfo()

    elif choice == "4":
        contact = AddressBook().delContact()

    elif choice == "5":
        contact = AddressBook().contactSearch()

    else:
        continue
```

I apologise for the mixture of pygame code and raw python code, as I still haven't fully transitioned the shell code into code that's usable by pygame. So contact entries etc are still done via the Shell/console. I first want to complete the main screen before I move on to actually being able to pass inputs via pygame.

Comment: I wouldn't use PyGame for this kind of application. There are better modules - Tkinter, PyQt, PySide, wxPython - with scrolled widgets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As furas already said in a comment, it's better to use a GUI framework like Tkinter or PyQt etc., especially since text input will be a major PITA for you if you stick with pygame. There are some widget libraries for pygame, but they all suck IMHO compared to a "real" GUI framework.

Nonetheless, there's an easy way to add scrolling to your application. Instead of drawing your stuff directly to the screen, blit it to an intermediate `Surface` that is higher than the screen `Surface`. If you want to scroll down, just blit this intermediate `Surface` "above" the screen `Surface`.

Here's a simple example of scrolling with a mouse wheel:

```
import pygame
import string

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
intermediate = pygame.surface.Surface((300, 600))
i_a = intermediate.get_rect()
x1 = i_a[0]
x2 = x1 + i_a[2]
a, b = (255, 0, 0), (60, 255, 120)
y1 = i_a[1]
y2 = y1 + i_a[3]
h = y2-y1
rate = (float((b[0]-a[0])/h),
         (float(b[1]-a[1])/h),
         (float(b[2]-a[2])/h)
         )
for line in range(y1,y2):
     color = (min(max(a[0]+(rate[0]*line),0),255),
              min(max(a[1]+(rate[1]*line),0),255),
              min(max(a[2]+(rate[2]*line),0),255)
              )
     pygame.draw.line(intermediate, color, (x1, line),(x2, line))

y = 20
f = pygame.font.SysFont('', 17)
for l in string.ascii_uppercase:
    intermediate.blit(f.render(l, True, (255, 255, 255)), (10, y))
    y += 20

clock = pygame.time.Clock()    
quit = False

scroll_y = 0

while not quit:
    quit = pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 4: scroll_y = min(scroll_y + 15, 0)
            if e.button == 5: scroll_y = max(scroll_y - 15, -300)

    screen.blit(intermediate, (0, scroll_y))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. I know PyGame isn't ideal for this sort of work but as this is a uni assignment they _want_ me to use this module for some reason and an Address Book app to be made from it. A couple of questions, is there a reason for `pygame.time.Clock()` to be used? And does the gradient give the illusion of scrolling?

Comment: Using `pygame.time.Clock()` ensures a constant framerate. Maybe it's not super important for your application, but for games it is and it's a good habit to always use it IMHO. I added the gradient only so the example looks nicer and you can see the scrolling better than with only the letters (since it's just a low quality animated gif image). It's in no way necessary.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to help me with this, it is very much appreciated.